# How to make custom wrapper for 2 field groups with ngx-formly?

Tags: angular, forms, ngx-formly

I'm quite confused how to make a layout for my form with fields using ngx-formly. For example, I've got 2 field groups: General and Dynamic.
[image: Example]

How to specify that general will be in one div, and dynamic in another div inside one dropdown(div)?

Official example looks like:
Wrapper:

```
 <div class="card">
      <h3 class="card-header">{{ to.label }}</h3>
      <div class="card-body">
        <ng-container #fieldComponent></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Component:

```
fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'firstName',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        required: true,
        type: 'text',
        label: 'First Name',
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'address',
      wrappers: ['panel'],
      templateOptions: { label: 'Address' },
      fieldGroup: [{
        key: 'town',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
          required: true,
          type: 'text',
          label: 'Town',
        },
      }],
    },
  ];
```

And here `<ng-container #fieldComponent></ng-container>` which doesn't specify which exactly field it is

Answer (score 8):

just put them inside a `fieldGroup` and either use a custom wrapper or custom type to render the `dropdown-dev`:

1. using custom type: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u4hep4
2. using custom wrapper: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjleoz

*note*: if you want to control a specified field you may use a custom type.

Comment: In the first StackBlitz, file `dropdown-dev.type.ts`, line 8, i see `to.label`. Can you please explain where that `to` is coming from?

Comment: @JamesPoulose `to` is an alias of `field.templateOptions` https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/blob/v5/src/core/src/lib/templates/field.type.ts#L25

Comment: @a.aitboudad getting an error " Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'formly-field' ".

Comment: @aashirkhan make sure FormlyModule and CommonModule are imported in the Module where the custom type/wrapper is declared.

Comment: This may not be directly related to my issue so far, but this answer and the comments taught me that `to`, `formControl` etc. are even at all available in a wrapper. Thank you so much!