# Angular 10 - Formly - Accessing a field's value in a custom formly-wrapper

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I am using Angular 10 and have a [formly-form](https://formly.dev) that includes a select-field called `session`. That select field allows me to choose one of several `dndSession` options. The value of each option is an object with a couple key-value pairs.

I'd like to be able to have next to my select-field a button that opens a modal-component `app-session-update-modal`. I planned to add it using a [custom field-wrapper](https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-wrapper) called `session-edit-wrapper` that I give to the `wrapper` option of `session`'s `FormlyFieldConfig`. I want to bind the currently selected `dndSession`-object to my `app-session-update-modal`-component, so that I can edit it there. This is where I'm running into problems.

How do I access the value of a field in a wrapper (In the blow HTML that is the ng-container `fieldComponent`) to bind it to an attribute on my modal-component? Is there an event I can use? (I tried ngModelChange so far as below with no success)

I know I'll need to bind the `dndSession`-objects as a [`Subject<dndSession>` (from rxjs)](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject), since I always want the button to lead to an edit of the currently selected `dndSession`. But how do I make that connection?

Below is the current HTML of my Wrapper, which I'm aware is pretty wrong, but I am only guessing currently what the correct Syntax would look like. The goal is, as stated, to bind a `Subject<dndSession>`-object to the `session_subject` attribute of my modal component:

```
//session-update-wrapper.html
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="flex-1">
        <ng-container #fieldComponent (ngModelChange)="sessionPkSubject.next(#fieldComponent.value)"></ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2">
        <app-session-update-modal [session_pk_subject]="sessionPkSubject"></app-session-update-modal>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
//session-update-wrapper.ts
... //Skipped over imports and the @Component decorator
export class SessionUpdateWrapperComponent extends FieldWrapper implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  sessionPkSubject : Subject<number>;

  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.sessionPkSubject = new Subject();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void{
    this.sessionPkSubject.complete();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56321390/how-to-make-custom-wrapper-for-2-field-groups-with-ngx-formly) from @a.aitboudad to an unrelated question and its comments below I managed to piece together, that you have access to various variables in a component wrapper, including `formControl`. I believe that is due to the class it inherits from. Either way, the variables you have access to can be seen [on this github page](https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/blob/v5/src/core/src/lib/templates/field.type.ts#L25).

With access to `formControl` of the select-field, we can grab its Observable `formControl.valueChanges` to get the selected Value over time with a subscription.

```
//session-update-wrapper.ts
export class SessionUpdateWrapperComponent extends FieldWrapper {}
```

```
//session-update-wrapper.html
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="flex-1">
        <ng-container #fieldComponent></ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2">
        <app-session-update-modal [session_pk_observable]="formControl.valueChanges"></app-session-update-modal>
    </div>
</div>
```